# Реализовать уведомления похожие на пуш-уведомления

Tags: javascript, reactjs, уведомления

Есть два юзера, один отправляет запрос на подтверждение консультации другому. На бэке у этой консультации состояние становится пэндинг.
Надо чтоб другому юзеру приходило это уведомление с возможностью подтвердить или отклонить ее, как бы пуш-уведомления(эндпоинт есть для изменения статуса).
Эндпоинты откуда получать консультации со статусом пэндинг тоже есть.

У меня есть предложения, например, отправлять запрос каждые 10 секунд. Это сильно повлияет на производительность?

Как это можно реализовать по-другому?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать для этого WebSocket или Server Sent Events. Но куда лучше Long Polling. Именно это и позволит вам отправлять каждые 10 сек. По сравнению с WebSocket эта операция менее затратная